# How fix package.json in vs code extension pack

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I created an extension pack named Kholiqiyon Pack. Published it on the vscode marketplace. Now I would like to add more to the extension and update it. I added new entries in `package.json` and the question is now how how to run `package.json` and save it. I need your helps.

[image]

Comment: No run, but simple `vsce package` or `vsce publish` in the same folder.

Comment: be sure to change the version (increase) number before publish, read the doc on how to publish an extension, updating is done identical